# How can I dynamically create a list of all Android ui components programmatically? e.g. TextView, ImageView etc

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I'm creating a program, and within which I need to create a list of all the different Android components but rather than figuring out and typing the **List** by hand. I'd like to figure out programmatically whether I could accomplish this to be added to String Arrays like the below?

```
Components[] = {"TextView", "ImageView", "RelativeLayout", "LinearLayout", "Random", "DecimalFormat ...
```

Similarly I would like to programatically create a **List** of all the different Data-Types e.g. Int, String, ArrayList etc. to be added to String Arrays like the below

```
DataTypes[] = {"Int", "String", "Object", "Double", "Char", "Boolean ...
```

**What I have been able to do so far**, is above. So far I've been physically typing them out as above.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks

**Clarification**

**By data types:** I mean variables types declared to holds data e.g Int, String, object, boolean, double, arrays, arraylists etc.

**By Components:** I mean any visual component which can be added to an Android's xml e.g. ImageView, TextView, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc.

Yes, I know the number of these components can be infinite (determined by the APIs in use), for which i would like to generate them dynamically

**Preferably without using someone else's library**

Comment: You want a list of all these components that exist in all of Android, or just the components and data types used in your application?

Comment: Programmatically, all existing in Android

Comment: Do you want to make a list of UI components without using ListView??

Comment: Just post what ur able to do so far.

Comment: Explained above, so far what I've been able to accomplish is above. And I'm wanting these to be added to string arrays as above

Comment: Can you define what makes a class a "Component" and what makes it a "Data-Type"?

Comment: Does this question make sense? Aren't there unlimited "components"? They are just classes ... and everybody can create new ones ...

Comment: Updated above to answer latest 2 questions

Comment: You can do this with reflection - but you should ask yourself if you really want to do what you ask for

Answer (score 10):

***You don't have to use any third-party libraries***, since `Java` has [reflections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). 
This method will do everything for you and make the `UI` without problems:

```
for(String s : arrayWithNames){
    View view = createViewInstance(0, s);
    if(view instance of View){
        //handle if it is view
    }else{
        //this is viewgroup
    }
}
```

And `createViewInstance()`:

```
private View createViewInstance(String name){
    View view = null;
    try{
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("View"){ // if it is view
            Class viewClass = Class.forName("android.view." + name);
            view = (View) viewClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(new Object[]{ctx});
        }else{ // if it is widget: ImageView, RelativeLayout etc
            Class viewClass = Class.forName("android.widget." + name);
            view = (View) viewClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(new Object[]{ctx});
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
            | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
}
```

That's it. You have everything to handle any kind of `View`.
***I've tested the code above and used in project. It works just fine.***
Exactly same situation with other `Object`s. You cannot create `int` with reflection, but you can create `Integer`, so what basically is same.

One problem with it there are much more types than just `View` and `ViewGroup`. But it also depends on how many kinds of `Object`s you want to create... In given example let's say I'll do `char`, `String`, `int`, `Object` and then you can easily extend it.

```
for(String s : arrayWithNames){
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("int")){
        Integer integer = (Integer)createVarInstance(s); //ready to use. Integer, not int!
    }else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("String"){
        String string = (String)createVarInstance(s);
    }else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("char"){
        Character character = (Character)createVarInstance(s); //Character, not char!
    }else if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("Object"){
        Object object = (Object)createVarInstance(s);
    }
}
```

Since all those data type are in the same package it makes much more easier for us. Method `createVarInstance()`:

```
private Object createVarInstance(String name){
    Object obj = null;
    try{
        Class varClass = Class.forName("java.lang." + name);
        object = (Object) varClass.newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
            | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
```

If it will be desired it is possible to make the one method for different packages.
If in future you want to create more and different types of variables, which are in different packages, so you will have to check names or do similar operations as in example with `View`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can list UI components all the classes into the [`android.view`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) package or the [`android.view.View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) sub-classes using [The Reflection Library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections):

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("android.view");
//Reflections reflections = new Reflections("android.view.View");

Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

To create a list of all the data-type you could do the same above using th Object class, but first, I'd personally ask myself what's the point doing this.

Answer (score 1):

[Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) is an awesome library for Java. I'm not sure if it works on Android too. Someone [opened an issue](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/14), it got closed soon after with no explanation.

If you can get it to work in Android, you can use this code to get all Components:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflection("android.widget") //specifiy the package (TextView etc. are in here)
Set<Class<? extends View>> components = reflections.getSubTypesOf(View.class);
```

If you want, you can repeat this procedure with the `android.view` package, where some other classes such as [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) are located.

Also, if you really want a String Array, get the names of the classes:

```
List<String> componentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Class<? extends View> c: components) {
    componentNames.add(c.getName());
}
String[] allComponents = componentNames.toArray();
```

---

If the above solution doesn't work for you, try getting the classes from the official website. The classes are listed in the packages [android.view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html) and [android.widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html). Just copy the relevant names and paste them in your source code. This wouldn't be dynamic, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

how about use a Factory to create Component like this:

```
public class ComponentFactory {
    private HashMap<String, View> mMap;
    public ComponentFactory(Context context) {
        mMap = new HashMap<String, View>();
        mMap.put("TextView", new TextView(context));
        ...
        ...
    }

    public View getComponent(String name) {
        View v = mMap.get(name);
        if (v == null) {
            throw new IlllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can we provide action for the created element, for example if i want to get text from edit text or get selected item from Spinner ? if you have sample please share here